# tagged push notification to android (google cloud messaging) using azure

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure's Notification Hubs REST APIs to create a ***Native registration for Google Cloud Messaging*** with a tag. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223264.aspx)

The API call runs successfully and returns a **RegistrationId** as well as my tags in the XML response:

```
<GcmRegistrationDescription
    <RegistrationId>222222222222222222222-1111111111111111111-2</RegistrationId>
    <Tags>toto ,titi</Tags>
</GcmRegistrationDescription>
```

However with the debug console, I fail to push a message to that tag with the error below:

> No registrations with the tag "toto" were found for the selected platform.

The **Read Registration** method of the REST api does not return the tags either. It returns an **Etag** element.

```
<GcmRegistrationDescription>
    <ETag>4</ETag>
    <RegistrationId>222222222222222222222-1111111111111111111-2</RegistrationId>
</GcmRegistrationDescription>
```

The same works great for the iPhone when creating a ***Native registration for Apple Push Notification Service***.

Any ideas on what I missed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just in case someone has the same problem, it can be bypassed by creating "Template Registrations" instead of native ones.

Comment: I wonder if Azure might not be updating a previously existing registration. Have you tried deleting any existing registration for the channel?

Comment: @AlanMcBee I have not tried. Thanks for your comment!